# How to pass a function with arguments to another function

Tags: bash, function, parameters, autocomplete

I'm trying to make a generic autocomplete function (which actually takes several parameters, and has a bunch of shared logic), so that I can easily and neatly maintain a long list of similar commands, with similar autocompletes (number of arguments, etc).

I've got a bash function, which takes an argument (simplified as much as possible):

```
_autocomplete() {
    COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "$1" -- "${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}") )
    return 0
}
```

And when I reference it, using a command which takes a function name as an argument, I want to also pass it a parameter to run in the function:

```
complete -F "_autocomplete example_param" some_function
```

However, this does not work when I hit tab, and instead errors with:

```
some_function bash: completion: function `_autocomplete example_param' not found
```

Is this a limitation of `complete`?
Is there any way around this, or a better approach?

Thanks.

Comment: Use `-C` to specify a command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-F` option is supposed to be followed by just a function name. If you want to execute a command with options, you need to use `-C`. But the command is required to print the completions to standard output, not set `COMPREPLY`. So change the function to:

```
_autocomplete() {
    COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "$1" -- "${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}") )
    for reply in "${COMPREPLY[@]}"
    do
        printf '%s\n' "$reply"
    done
    return 0
}

complete -C "_autocomplete example_param" some_function
```